# Incorrect Extraction of fields in Splunk

Tags: field, extract, splunk

I tried to perform 'add extraction' in the Splunk on the following data :

**Line 771927: ERR: N17739 Limit switch X- 30.05.2015 23:28:26.405**

I want  'Line 771927: ERR:'  as one field, 'ERR: N17739 Limit switch X-'  as another one field, '30.05.2015'  as another one field and  '23:28:26.405'  as last field.

When I tried to extract,this line worked perfect but the below line throws error:

**Line 772014: ERR: N17738 Limit switch Y+ 30.05.2015 23:32:10.694**

Though both the lines have same pattern, I am not able to extract second one.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Which version of Splunk are you using?

I created a new file with those 2 lines and index it.
I was able to create 2 separate field extractions that worked fine. The regexes generated were `(?i)^(?P<err>\w+\s+\d+:\s+\w+:)` and `(?i) ERR: (?P<limit>.+?)\s+\d+`

Comment: Sorry Shakeel for the late comment.